# Convert OpenCV keypoints to CGPoint

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv

Currently, I am object tracking with OpenCV. When OpenCV returns the keypoints of where the objects are, they are out of the range of the iPhone screen. I'm thinking that there is some sort of conversion that needs to be done in order to use these points with swift.

Does anyone know the conversion that needs to be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cvPoint values are image coordinates (if the tracking algorithm is valid). You can mark these points on the image using cvCircle and then display the image on the iPhone screen to check if they are valid.
When an image is displayed on the screen using UIImageView, the size of the displayed image might not be the same as the image resolution. In that case, you will need to scale the coordinates, if you want to position something on the image. See [here](http://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image/) for an example.

Comment: I'm finding that that is what my problem is. Any idea how to do that? I have been dividing the (x,y) coordinates returned by the multiple that the pixel resolution is bigger than the screen size of the iPhone. For example the iPhone 6+'s pixel resolution is 1920X1080 while the screen size is 736X414. When you divide each colXrow you get 2.6. That 2.6 value is what I have been dividing my coordinates by. Is that the right way I should be thinking about this?

Comment: If  you just want to see the results, the best way is to draw markers on the actual image using cv::Circle, cv::Line, cv:: rectangle etc. But if you want to add buttons, view or other controls using the result, you have to scale down the results as you mentioned. The tutorial at http://www.appcoda.com/face-detection-core-image/ explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Totoro I'll give that a shot